# Java Thread crashing but Swing is still working

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi

for some cell in XLSX file rt.getFontAtIndex(i) part is just crashing and control is just exiting the function and even calling function. Out Swing windows is still open though. I have no clues why without any exception control is going out of the code.

```
    public static String addLinkTagInRichTextForUnderscores(XSSFRichTextString rt) {
        System.out.print("Was here 1\n");
        if(rt.length()==0 || rt == null) {
            return " ";
        }
        String outString = rt.toString();
        //String finalString = "";
        List<Integer> startIndexListOfUL = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        boolean continuing = false;
        System.out.println(outString +" A "+ rt.length() +"\n\n");

        for(int i=1;i<rt.length();i++) {
            System.out.print("Was here at font "+ i);
            XSSFFont font = null;
            try{
            //font = rt.getFontAtIndex(i);
            } catch(Error e){
                e.fillInStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print("Was here too" + rt.getFontAtIndex(i));
            if(font!= null) {
                if(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE == font.getUnderline()) {

                    if(!continuing){
                        startIndexListOfUL.add(new Integer(i));
                        continuing = true;
                    }

                }else{
                    continuing = false;
                }
            } else {
                //System.out.println("No font " + i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(startIndexListOfUL);

        if(startIndexListOfUL.size()==0) {
            //finalString = outString;
            return " ";
        } else {
            int spacing = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<startIndexListOfUL.size(); i++) {
                outString =     insertStringAt(outString,startIndexListOfUL.get(i) + spacing,"<link>");
                spacing = spacing + 6;
            }
        }

        //just remove redundant <link> tags
        outString = outString.replaceAll("(<link>[\\s]?<link>)", "<link>");
        //System.out.println("Final >>>> " + outString);
        return outString;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that your Swing GUI would crash in this situation? It will only behave as you (your code) tell it to behave. How do you handle your Swing threading? How do you tell Swing to respond to crashes in the non-GUI thread?

Comment: In fact, I see no threading code, no SwingWorker code, and in fact no Swing code at all in your post above, making it very hard to understand what in fact you might be doing, and you you're handling exceptions. Are you using a SwingWorker? If so, are you calling the SwingWorker's `get()` method? And if so, are you catching the exceptions it might throw?  ....

Comment: Wsing worker was calling one class function which intern was calling above mentioned class. Issue has been resolved. XSSFRichTextString has the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "why is my Swing GUI application not crashing despite the crashing of a background thread?", the answer is that Swing GUI's are no different from other Java programs. If you crash a thread in any program, and 1) the exception doesn't cause the JVM to crash, and 2) the exception information doesn't percolate up into the calling code, the calling code will be blissfully unaware that anything has happened.

The solution is to inform the Swing GUI when this happens. For instance if you're using a SwingWorker to create your background thread, its `get()` method will pass any exceptions that may have happened inside the SwingWorker's doInBackground method.  For example:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTest {
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private JTextField numberField = new JTextField("5x", 5);

   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public SwingTest() {
      MyFailAction myFailAction = new MyFailAction();
      numberField.setAction(myFailAction);
      mainPanel.add(new JLabel("String to parse into an int:"));
      mainPanel.add(numberField);
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(myFailAction));
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class MyFailAction extends AbstractAction {

      public MyFailAction() {
         super("Push to Fail");
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_P);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         String text = numberField.getText();
         final MySwingWorker mySw = new MySwingWorker(text);
         mySw.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
               if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("state")) {
                  if (evt.getNewValue().equals(SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE)) {
                     try {
                        // **** here I call get() on my SwingWorker ****
                        int value = mySw.get();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "value is "
                              + value);
                     } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        if (e.getCause() instanceof NumberFormatException) {
                           String message = "A NumberFormatException has occurred when trying to parse \""
                                 + numberField.getText() + "\" to an int\n" +
                                 "Reseting field to \"0\"";
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, message,
                                 "NumberFormatException",
                                 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.append(e.getMessage() + "\n");
                        for (StackTraceElement ele : e.getStackTrace()) {
                           sb.append(ele.toString() + "\n");
                        }
                        sb.append("\n");
                        sb.append("*****   Cause:   *****\n");
                        sb.append(e.getCause().getLocalizedMessage());
                        for (StackTraceElement ele : e.getCause()
                              .getStackTrace()) {
                           sb.append(ele.toString() + "\n");
                        }
                        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(sb.toString());
                        JScrollPane message = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, message,
                              "Error Specifics", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        numberField.setText("0");
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         });
         mySw.execute();
      }
   }

   private class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Void> {
      private static final long SLEEP_DELAY = 1000;
      private String text;

      public MySwingWorker(String text) {
         this.text = text;
      }

      @Override
      protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
         Thread.sleep(SLEEP_DELAY);
         int value = Integer.parseInt(text);
         return value;
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwingTest swingTest = new SwingTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwingTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(swingTest.getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for XSSFRichTextString.getFontAtIndex() says it will return an XSSFFont, or null if no font is applied or the index is out of range.  So you need to see if the return value is null before using it (including in a System.out.print call), otherwise you will get a NullPointerException and control will leave the code block.

Also, note that catching an Error will not help - an NPE is a RuntimeException, not a subclass of Error and thus won't be caught in your try/catch block anyhow.  With a few exceptions (no pun intended), you should put the proper checks in your code (make sure returned references are not null, check indexes against array length, etc.) rather than trying to catch unchecked exceptions.

Comment: Actually I found the bug in the XSSFRichTextString. The class was internally crashing and it did not have null pointer handling.Also swingworker was not able to forward me the nullpointerexception too. So I was not able to understand why code was failing and where.